# How can I use a For loop to loop tabs on sheet index numbers in Google Apps Script?

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I use 'i' to loop through the sheet index numbers?

I tried this:

```
function myFunction() {
  
  for (var i = 2; i < 14; i++);{
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 
  spreadsheet.getSheets()[i].getRange('J10').setFormula('=iferror(VLOOKUP($B9,\'STUDENT SCORES\'!AL46:AM49,2,FALSE)," ")');
 
  }
}
```

But it does not work.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this sample script:-

```
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var i = 2; i < spreadsheets.length; i++);{    
  spreadsheets[i].getRange('J10')
  .setFormula('=iferror(VLOOKUP($B9,\'STUDENT SCORES\'!AL46:AM49,2,FALSE)," ")');     
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried the solution but still got "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of undefined"

Comment: That's because your spreadsheet doesn't have enough sheet to match the iterations loop, why you want to use `var i = 2 ; i < 14`??

Comment: Yeah, there weren't enough sheets. I changed it to <=13 and it worked. Thank you for your help!